# How to correctly return a json string from python flask server

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, swagger-editor

I am using a python flask server API to call another python flask server API.  Both these have been generated using swagger editor.

API2 returns an encoded string such as:

```
def Server2_API2():
    payload = {
        "value1": 'somedata',
        "value2": 'somedata',
    }
    encoded_payload = jwt.encode(payload, SECRET, algorithm=ALGORITHM)
    return encoded_payload <-- {str}'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.'
```

API1 on server 1 calls API2 on server 2 as follows:

```
def Server1_API1():
    resp = requests.post('http://localhost:1000/API2', data='value1=one&value2=two')
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        first_try = resp.content   <-- b'"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9"\n'
        second_try = resp.content.decode() <-- {str} '"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9"
        '   <- notice the new line here

        return first_try
        #return second_try
```

If I return **first_try** then I get the error: **Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable**

If I return **second_try** then I get the following data returned:

```
"\"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9\"\n"
```

My goal is to have just the data returned as follows without any error or any back slashes or new lines:

e.g.    "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9"

How can I achieve this?

**SOLUTION:**

third_try = resp.json()  <-- This does the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick:

```
token = resp.json()
```